# Unable to call one loopback app models in another looopback app using loopback-connector-remote

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have created two test loopback apps using lb cli

```
1) loopbacktest1
2) loopbacktest2
```

And I am using loopback-connector-remote to get access of loopbacktest2 
models in loopbacktest1, but I could not access it and I could not even
see app2 models in app1 at all(vice verse as well), Can anyone help me?

Here is my datasoureces

```
{
 "db": {
 "name": "db",
 "connector": "memory"
 },
"MyMicroService": {
 "name": "MyMicroService",
 "connector": "remote",
 "url": "http://localhost:7001/api"
 }
}
```

**Updating question with final answer:-**

Add below config in json file(this is the remote method name)

```
  todos.json
  "methods": {
    "getName": {
      "returns": {
      "arg": "data",
      "type": "string"
     },
     "http": {
       "verb": "get"
     }
   }
  }
```

And call that remote method like this

```
const remoteDs = ModelName.app.dataSources.MyMicroService;
  // the strong-remoting RemoteObjects instance
  const remotes = remoteDs.connector.remotes;
  remotes.auth = {
    bearer: `${access_token}`,
    sendImmediately: true
  };
  MyMicroService.app.models.todos.getName(function (err, data) {
    cb(err, data);
  });
  // cb(null, data);
}).catch((err) => {
  cb("sone error", null);
});
```

Here still I am facing some small issue, that is if above authentication fails then I am getting err as null and data as undefined, Instead I am expecting error value and data as null.There might be some issue in loopback-connector-remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `loopbacktest2` models in `loopbacktest1` as well, indicating that the datasource to be used is `MyMicroService`.

If you follow the example at https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-example-connector/tree/remote then you should have a `client` subdirectory containing several files including `model-config.json` where you should add `loopbacktest1` models with `MyMicroService` as datasource.

And within common/models a json file for each of those models, containing at least the bare definition, something like https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-example-connector/blob/remote/common/models/person.json

I've followed that example and got it working in no time.

I've handled authentication this way:

```
const app = require('./client/client');
const User = app.models.User;
const MyModel = app.models.MyModel;
// the remote datasource (as defined in datasources.json)
const remoteDs = app.dataSources.remoteDS;
// the strong-remoting RemoteObjects instance
const remotes = remoteDs.connector.remotes;
/*
   credentials.json example (I keep it untracked by git):

   {
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "password": "123456"
   }

*/
const credentials = require('./credentials.json');

User.login(credentials).then(token => {
    // store the token to allow logout
    credentials.token = token;

    // set the access token to be used for all future invocations
    remotes.auth = {
        bearer: (new Buffer(token.id)).toString('base64'),
        sendImmediately: true
    };

    /* from this point every request made by any model attached 
       to remoteDS will be authenticated */
    return MyModel.find();
}, err => {
    // handle auth error
}).then(models => {
    console.log(`Got ${models.length} instances!`);
});
```

Comment: Hey @MrTorture Thanks for your help, Now I could call app1 models in app2.  Do you know how to add authorization to these call? Basically these apps are authentication protected, so I need to pass access token as well. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Just edited my answer to include an example of how to handle authentication.